# Can any sklearn module return average precision and recall scores for negative class in k-fold cross validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to get the mean of precision and recall for BOTH positive and negative class in a 10-fold cross validation. My model is a binary classifier.

I ran the codes below and unfortunately it only returned the mean precision and recall for the positive class. How can I tell the algorithm to return the mean precision and recall scores for the negative class as well?

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
           'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score),
           'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score), 
           'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score)}

results = cross_validate(model_unbalanced_data_10_times_weight, X, Y, cv=10, scoring=scoring)

np.mean(results['test_precision'])
np.mean(results['test_recall'])
```

I've also tried printing the classification report using the command "`classification_report(y_test, predictions)`" which resulted in the printout in screenshot below. However, I believe the precision/recall scores from the classification report is based on 1 run only and not the average over 10 folds (correct me if I am wrong).

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) from `sklearn.metrics`? It provides precision/recall scores by class which seems to fit yuor need.

Comment: @anddt, I've tried classification_report. If I understand correctly, it only provides the precision/recall for one run and not the average overall k folds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion above, I do believe that computing predictions for every cv fold and computing `cross_validation_report` on them should be the right way to go. Results should now take the number of cv folds into account:

```py
>>> from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
>>> 
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> 
>>> rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
>>> 
>>> preds = cross_val_predict(estimator=rf_clf,
...                           X=iris["data"],
...                           y=iris["target"],
...                           cv=15)
>>> 
>>> print(classification_report(iris["target"], preds))
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00        50
           1       0.92      0.94      0.93        50
           2       0.94      0.92      0.93        50

    accuracy                           0.95       150
   macro avg       0.95      0.95      0.95       150
weighted avg       0.95      0.95      0.95       150
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `cross_val_predict` is not the way to go, because as stated in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict): *"Passing these predictions into an evaluation metric may not be a valid way to measure generalization performance. Results can differ from cross_validate and cross_val_score unless all tests sets have equal size and the metric decomposes over samples."*

I would suggest:

```
rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier()

scoring = {'precision_positive_class': make_scorer(precision_score),
           'precision_negative_class': make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label=0),
           'recall_positive_class': make_scorer(recall_score),
           'recall_negative_class': make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=0)}

results = cross_validate(rf_clf, X=iris["data"], y=iris["target"],
                         scoring=scoring,
                         return_train_score=True)

# Calculate averages of NEGATIVE class
np.mean(results['test_precision_negative_class'])
np.mean(results['test_recall_negative_class'])
```